# Can the 3-dimensional Cauchy inequality be certified by 2 squares?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The Lagrange identity writes $(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2) - (ax+ by+cz)^2$ as a sum of 3 squares of real polynomials, namely $[(ay-bx)]^2 + [(az-cx)]^2 + [(bz-cy)]^2$. Do 2 squares suffice?

Comment: I'd like to see that identity put into the question. (Lagrange has a four-square identity to his name, but this one is (to me) maybe lesser known and would be good to include.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity

Comment: Check it again, the three polynomials on the right should not have the $\sqrt{2}$ denominators. So Lagrange writes your left side as a sum of 3 squares of integer polynomials (better than just real polynomials!)

Comment: Yes, the $\sqrt{2}$ should not be there. I did not know the Cauchy inequality was related to the problem of writing a positive integer as a sum of 4 squares.

Answer (score 0):

If $(a,b,c,x,y,z)=(1,1,2,1,2,3)$ this expression gives the value $3$, which is not the sum of two squares. So there can't be an algebraic way to express it as a sum of two squares. (That is, not such a sum of two squares of polynomials with integer coefficients...)

ADDED: If one takes the usual four square Lagrange identity for expressing the product $(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2)$ as a sum of four squares, one of the terms is the square of $(ax+by+cz+dt).$ Then if one puts $d=t=0$ in the LaGrange identity, and moves $(ax+by+cz)^2$ to the left side, one has the expression of the post as the sum of three squares. So it is really a special case of the Lagrange identity (likely this is already known by the OP, but it wasn't in the post).

Now if the right side of the expression of the post were a sum of squares of two simple polynomials, then by moving again the subtracted square back to the right side, one would arrive at a "generic" way to express the product of two positive integers each representable as a sum of *three* squares as a single sum of three squares. It's sort of "well known" there is no such formula, and that fact is what is behind the added difficulty for representing integers as sums of three squares, since one cannot use the LaGrange trick (for four squares) to reduce everything to considering the representation of primes as sums of three squares and then applying the supposed identity.

Since this has been attempted for three squares there may be a rigorous proof of nonexistence around somewhere, but in my opinion the above example [the form represents $3$ which isn't a sum of two squares] shows at least that the attempt to finish using the specific subtracted square $(ax+by+cz)^2$ cannot work.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720773/does-there-exist-bivariate-polynomials-p-and-q-such-that-px-y2-qx-y There is some kind of theme here. Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720937/can-the-cubic-mean-geometric-mean-inequality-by-a-sum-of-8-weighted-squares

Comment: @WillJagy Yes I see OP is after something different than what my answer aimed at. I'll delete it.

Comment: I'm not sure, this may be exactly what is desired; certainly was not specific in the question, and your answer gives some insight.

Comment: Coffeemath, I learnt something from your answer, especially from your edit. Probably we can prove that that 3 squares does not suffice, given that we restrict ourselves to polynomials with rational coefficients. Can the arithmetical argument still carry through if we allow real coefficients?

Comment: @ColinTan -- With real coefficients allowed no arithmetic argument is useful, as one can just set the two other squares to the given left side over $\sqrt{2}.$ Also the example in this answer already shows one cannot have three squares if one of them is taken to be $(ax+by+cz)^2$ and the other two must be polynomials with integer coefficients. It would be much harder to rule out *any* combination of three polynomials squared to equal the product $(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2).$ This latter may have been done already by someone, I don't know the literature well enough to say.

Comment: @coffeemath thank you for explaining why three squares of polynomials with integer coefficients is not possible.

Comment: @ColinTan As noted, I only explained three not possible provided one of them is $(ax+by+cz)^2.$ Without that restriction it would be harder to prove.

Comment: @coffeemath thanks for clarifying this point.